# NDK and Android 1.5

Tags: android, android-ndk

My Android mixed (Java/NDK) project was going along nicely. Then suddenly I got a report that the native library failed to load on Android 1.5.

On the emulator, it reproduced perfectly. There's an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` thrown on the `System.loadLibrary()` call. The message says "library can't be found", but it's right there. Earlier versions of the app worked on Android 1.5; but I didn't test every single build on it.

I don't remember introducing any new RTL calls recently. Moreover, I've dumped all my imported symbols with `readelf -s mylib.so | grep UND` and matched them against `readelf -s` output for libc.so and libstdc++.so, as pulled from the 1.5 emulator. All the symbols can be found in either of those libraries, with the exception of three:

- __cxa_begin_cleanup
- __cxa_type_match
- __cxa_call_unexpected

But those are weak references. They shouldn't cause an error. And also, I couldn't find them in Android 4.2's libraries either. Where do they reside? Are they indeed to blame?

If those symbols are causing the error, I didn't insert the dependency on them - the NDK toolchain did. Probably rebuilding against an older version of NDK libraries would help; is there a way to specify the NDK platform version to use on per-CPU_ABI basis? I'm building for all four CPU_ABI; in android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-3, only ARM can be found.

EDIT: rebuilding with

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
TARGET_PLATFORM := android-3
endif
```

doesn't help. Neither does scratching all but ARM and adding

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-3
```

to Application.mk.

Comment: As an experiment to narrow the problem, you can try using System.load() with a full path/file name instead of a library name.  Also check the execute bit.  You could make a test program that only loads the library after a button push, (manually?) connect gdbserver & gdb (or even just strace, if you can find one) to it, and watch what happens as you try to load the library.

Comment: Give a try to new ndk-depends, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/text/NDK-DEPENDS.text also I would go through https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/text/CHANGES.text to see if something looks suspicious for you.